Optimizely CMS - How do you access HyperLink Editor fields and modifiy them?

I've been trying to figure out a way to Modify the "Open in" field to say "Target".
Bonus : also change the string for the options of that field.
I've tried using this solution but "Open in" is not considered a Provider.
EditorDescriptor
Any ideas ?

You'd have to build your own editor for that
https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/content-management-system/docs/registering-a-custom-editor
https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/content-management-system/docs/creating-an-editor-widget
